# Chrome compatibility error

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser

Last week I created a virtual album but I have a compatibility problem with Chrome. Here's the site - [CLICK](http://www.class.comule.com)  . I can't figure out why the big images don't want to show in Chrome. The site works well in Opera, Firefox and even in IE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s.sorry for my English

Comment: just tested in chrome and looks good. whats the problem?

Comment: When I click the thumbs the big images don't want to show

Comment: any errors on the console? Also, there's way too much (not well formatted) code on that page. A snippet of the code that is failing would help

Comment: I can't find any errors. I agree that my code is not the prettiest but why it is displaying well on the other browsers... I hated Chrome :(

Answer (score 1):

I am running Chrome version 19.0.1084.52 m and it displays fine.  I can see the thumbnails at the bottom, click on them and they display the large image.

Comment: I use the same version but the images don't wannt to pop up... any ideas

Answer (score 1):

your html also have some problems:

double quotes problem:

```
<meta name="description" content="Виртуален албум на 12А клас випуск 2012 ПГ"Найден Геров" " />
<meta name="keywords" content="албум, випуск, album, 12 клас, 12a, 12а, PG Naiden Gerov, ПГ"Нйден Геров", найден геров, najden gerov, pg"/>
<meta property="og:description"
      content="Виртуален албум на 12а клас випуск 2012 ПГ"Найден Геров""/>
```

also, instead of `<style>` enter `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: ok, I corrected it, but again the big image doesn't pop up :(

Comment: the big (front?) image is showing nicely to me in my 19.0.1084.52 google chrome. what you have?

Comment: not the front, click on an item on the menu and then on some thumb and theoritically  the image must pop up

Comment: i did that also previously; images pop-ed out normally, although a bit slow. update your chrome and try again.

Comment: I installed Chrome on another pc with Xp an there the site works...I can't figure it out....

Answer (score 0):

Well I just loaded the website in Google Chrome 20 beta and had no problems loading the page, and navigation the albums.

It may seem a bit mundane, but make sure you're using the latest version of chrome, and check that no extensions are causing this glitch (a common culprit can be AdBlock extensions).

Chrome 20beta, Mac OSX 10.7.4

Comment: I don't have any extensions in Chrome(I am running Chrome version 19.0.1084.52 on Windows).

Comment: Is there a different between Windows and Mac's versions?

Comment: No.  Tried this on my Windows 7 x64 and it worked fine.